# Advisable to use rx distinct in long running process?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

i am using rx distinct operator to filter external data stream based on a certain key within a long running process.

will this cause leak in the memory? Assuming a lot of different keys will be received. How does rx distinct operator keep track of previously received keys?

Should I use groupbyuntil with a duration selector instead?

Comment: 3D-Grabber's answer notwithstanding (it's a fine answer), don't overlook the obvious and not test your code with a memory profiler. You should do that anyway if you are worried about memory leaks. Apologies if you've already considered this, but all too often I find people obsessing about possible leaks in APIs when a few minutes with a profiler would prove the API is fine *and* find the gaping leaks in their own code. :) At the very least you can measure the characteristics of your particular scenario.

Comment: thanks james, i took your advice and indeed we do have memory leaking on the distinct key by using the distinct operator on long running subscription. we have then changed to use group by until with closing duration selector, that resolved the memory leak issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Observable.Distinct` uses a `HashSet` internally. Memory usage will be roughly proportional to the number of distinct Keys encountered. (AFAIK about 30*n bytes)

`GroupByUntil` does something really different than `Distinct`. 
`GroupByUntil` (well) groups, whereas `Distinct` filters the elements of a stream.

Not sure about the intended use, but if you just want to filter *consecutive* identical elements you need `Observable.DistinctUntilChanged` which has a memory footprint independent of the number of keys.

Comment: HashSet, not HashMap.  In a HashSet, all keys are unique.  "For very large HashSet<T> objects, you can increase the maximum capacity to 2 billion elements on a 64-bit system by setting the enabled attribute of the gcAllowVeryLargeObjects configuration element to true in the run-time environment".

Comment: _HashSet, not HashMap_ => 
Fixed, thx, was stuck in the Java universe

Answer (score 1):

This may be a controversial tactic, but if you were worried about distinct keys accumulating, and if there was a point in time where this could safely be reset, you could introduce a reset policy using Observable.Switch. For example, we have a scenario where the "state of the world" is reset on a daily basis, so we could reset the distinct observable daily.

```
Observable.Create<MyPoco>(
    observer =>
    {
        var distinctPocos = new BehaviorSubject<IObservable<MyPoco>>(pocos.Distinct(x => x.Id));

        var timerSubscription =
            Observable.Timer(
                new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(1)),
                TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                schedulerService.Default).Subscribe(
                    t =>
                    {
                        Log.Info("Daily reset - resetting distinct subscription.");
                        distinctPocos.OnNext(pocos.Distinct(x => x.Id));
                    });

        var pocoSubscription = distinctPocos.Switch().Subscribe(observer);

        return new CompositeDisposable(timerSubscription, pocoSubscription);
    });
```

However, I do tend to agree with James World's comment above regarding testing with a memory profiler to check that memory is indeed an issue before introducing potentially unnecessary complexity. If you're accumulating 32-bit ints as the key, you'd have many millions of unique items before running into memory issues on most platforms. E.g. 262144 32-bit int keys will take up one megabyte. It may be that you reset the process long before this time, depending on your scenario.